# How to use DAO.Relation via VB6?

Tags: vb6, dao, invoices

I have inherited a VB6 project written using DAO on largely Access data.

The code is poor and the application often generates a Windows crash (program "has encountered a problem and needs to close") with large sets of data. I suspect large parts need rewriting.

I want to start with using DAO to relate a recordset of invoice headers (which has one record per invoice) and another of invoice lines (which has several records per invoice). Two fields link these recordsets: Date and Reference.

Though I have seen an example of creating a DAO.Relation, I have no idea how to use it and would welcome some advice please.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) before asking questions.

Comment: @Mario De Schaepmeester, I had read the FAQ! I thought my question was OK. Basically, how do I use DAO.Relation? The rest of my posting explains what I am trying to seek. What would you rather I had written?

Comment: I see now that your question is probably about VBA? I thought it was about Visual Basic programming... My bad

Comment: @Mario De Schaepmeester, the program is in VB6, as mentioned in my original posting!

Comment: If you're looking for a feature like .Net heirarchical datasets, there's nothing like that in DAO or ADO.

Comment: @markj thank you for the information; I am sure you are right! If you enter this as an answer, I will accept it and you can get your points.

Comment: @finch OK, have done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a feature like [.Net hierarchical datasets](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316260), there's nothing like that in DAO or ADO.